# Is there a way to deserialize script field values on a search result without an extra loop?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I need to use [Script Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-script-fields.html) in my .net code, in order to run some query logic on Elasticsearch. [This doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/script-fields-usage.html) says that:

> Script fields can be accessed on the response using [.Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/returned-fields.html), similarly
> to stored fields.

In order to retrieve the Script Fields results, it looks like I need to loop over the results (as suggested [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/returned-fields.html) or [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-search-version-6-7-nest-how-to-read-script-field-values-on-search-result/187783)). I want to avoid that loop, and somehow get the data within my call to NEST's client.search(), which already populates a list of results. Is that possible?

Here's my call:

```
    public async Task<List<SomeObj>> GetSomeDocsFromEs()
    {
        var result = await client.SearchAsync<SomeObj>(s => s
            .Index(...)
            .Query(...)
            .Size(...)
            .From(...)
            .Sort(...)
            .ScriptFields(sf => sf
                     .ScriptField("StoredField1", sc => sc
                        .Source(some Painless script)
                     )
                     .ScriptField("StoredField2", sc => sc
                        .Source(some Painless script)
                     )
                     .ScriptField("StoredField3", sc => sc
                        .Source(some Painless script)
                      )
                )
            .StoredFields(sf => sf
                    .Fields(
                            f => f.StoredField1,
                            f => f.StoredField2,
                            f => f.StoredField3
                    )
                )
            .Source(so => so
                .Includes(i => i
                    .Fields(f => f.SkuEntry.Field1,
                            f => f.SkuEntry.Field2,
                            f => f.SkuEntry.Field3
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        return result.Documents.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to avoid that loop, and somehow get the data within my call to NEST's client.search(), which already populates a list of results. Is that possible?

Script fields are returned ***for each hit*** in the hits array, so there's no way to avoid looping over hits.

`result.Documents` in the example maps to the `_source` field for each document, which is the original JSON object sent to Elasticsearch and indexed. It's a convenient shorthand for `result.Hits.Select(h => h.Source).ToList()`.

Script fields are not part of the `_source` document, they are returned in a separate field for each hit. `result.Fields` is a convenient shorthand for `result.Hits.Select(h => h.Fields).ToList()`.

As an example, given the following query

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<Project>(s => s
    .ScriptFields(sf => sf
        .ScriptField("test1", sc => sc
            .Source("doc['numberOfCommits'].value * 2")
        )
        .ScriptField("test2", sc => sc
            .Source("doc['numberOfCommits'].value * params.factor")
            .Params(p => p
                .Add("factor", 2.0)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which sends the following request

```json
{
  "script_fields": {
    "test1": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['numberOfCommits'].value * 2"
      }
    },
    "test2": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['numberOfCommits'].value * params.factor",
        "params": {
          "factor": 2.0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The JSON response is

```json
{
  "took" : 26,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1100,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "project",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Konopelski Inc2032",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "Konopelski Inc2032",
        "fields" : {
          "test2" : [
            308.0
          ],
          "test1" : [
            308
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "project",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Feest Group2047",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "Feest Group2047",
        "fields" : {
          "test2" : [
            1986.0
          ],
          "test1" : [
            1986
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To iterate over the script fields of each hit in the response

```cs
foreach (var fields in response.Fields)
{
    // do something with test1 and test2 values
    var test1 = fields.Value<int>("test1");
    var test2 = fields.Value<double>("test2");
}
```

Comment: is it possible to filter scripted fields by the next sub aggregation, for example bucket selector?
Let's say I want to filter in the bucket selector test1 from the fields like filter out everything that's less than 1980